# PHP echo doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, echo

I have the following PHP code:

```
$ep1 = $tvdb->getEpisodeById($cur->id, 'en');
var_dump($ep1);
```

It returns this:

```
object(TvDb\Episode)#60 (17) {
    ["id"]=> int(4490826)
    ["number"]=> int(12)
    ["season"]=>      int(3)
    ["directors"]=> array(0) { }
    ["guestStars"]=> array(0) { }        
    ["writers"]=> array(0) { }
    ["name"]=> string(11) "Episode 312"
    ["firstAired"]=> object(DateTime)#57 (3) {
        ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-04-07 00:00:00"
        ["timezone_type"]=> int(3)
        ["timezone"]=> string(12) "Europe/Sofia"
    }
    ["imdbId"]=> string(0) ""
    ["language"]=> string(2) "en"
    ["overview"]=> string(0) ""
    ["rating"]=> string(1) "0"
    ["ratingCount"]=> int(0)
    ["lastUpdated"]=> object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
        ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-01-30 22:15:41"
        ["timezone_type"]=> int(1)
        ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+00:00"
    }
    ["seasonId"]=> int(501077)
    ["serieId"]=> int(161511)
    ["thumbnail"]=> string(0) ""
}
```

I want to echo "date" and I write the following:

```
$ep1 = $tvdb->getEpisodeById($cur->id, 'en');
echo ($ep1->firstAired->date);
```

And it returns nothing, but when I do this:

```
$ep1 = $tvdb->getEpisodeById($cur->id, 'en');
var_dump($ep1);
echo ($ep1->firstAired->date);
```

And there after the dump the date shows:

```
object(TvDb\Episode)#60 (17) { ["id"]=> int(4490826) ["number"]=> int(12) ["season"]=> int(3) ["directors"]=> array(0) { } ["guestStars"]=> array(0) { } ["writers"]=> array(0) { } ["name"]=> string(11) "Episode 312" ["firstAired"]=> object(DateTime)#57 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-04-07 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(12) "Europe/Sofia" } ["imdbId"]=> string(0) "" ["language"]=> string(2) "en" ["overview"]=> string(0) "" ["rating"]=> string(1) "0" ["ratingCount"]=> int(0) ["lastUpdated"]=> object(DateTime)#3 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2013-01-30 22:15:41" ["timezone_type"]=> int(1) ["timezone"]=> string(6) "+00:00" } ["seasonId"]=> int(501077) ["serieId"]=> int(161511) ["thumbnail"]=> string(0) "" } 2013-04-07 00:00:0
```

I don't have this problem with:

```
$ep1 = $tvdb->getEpisodeById($cur->id, 'en');
echo ($ep1->name);
```

I hope I was clear enough and I'm sorry If it is a stupid question.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi. Try this: http://php.net/manual/ro/datetime.format.php .`echo $ep1->firstAired->date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: what did you expect `echo` would output when passed an object? unless an object has a "magic" `__toString` method, you will get nothing (and will even throw an error)

Comment: Yeah, I now it is stupid mistake, but I'm new to coding and PHP. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property `$ep1->firstAired` is a `DateTime` object.  You cannot access it's properties directly like you're trying.   You have to use the accessor methods like `format()`

```
   echo $ep1->firstAired->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is really, really weird, at least to me. I tested to echo out just the date property at first, just like you did, and it didn't work, then i decided to add a print_r to see the properties... And then I could print out the date-string.

This is my code:

```
$d = new DateTime();
print_r($d);
echo $d->timezone  . PHP_EOL;
echo $d->date  . PHP_EOL;
```

And doing it like this works just fine, however do I remove the `print_r` line it doesn't work.

My system is windows 8 with php 5.3 running in a shell, and here's my proof:

[image: Yet another PHP feature.]

So you could say that you can do this, you just have to do a print_r first, and it probably won't work on all systems. :D